# css :target - focus

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im using :target to change page content displayed which works no problem. But i'm having a issue where it jumps to the dom element selected by # in the url, which i would prefer not to do. So what i want to do is select a different point to jump too. This is in wordpress. Is there any way of dealing with this, maybe within the :target css?

html:

```
<article class="tabs">

<section id="Vehicle-Subscriptions">
    <h2><a href="#Vehicle-Subscriptions">Vehicles</a></h2>
    <p>Page 1</p>
</section>

<section id="Job-Subscriptions">
    <h2><a href="#Job-Subscriptions">Jobs</a></h2>
    <p>page 2</p>
</section>

<section id="Property-Subscriptions">
    <h2><a href="#Property-Subscriptions">Property</a></h2>
    <p>page 3</p>
</section>

</article>
```

css:

```
article.tabs
{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 90%;
   height: 15em;
   margin: 2em auto; 
}

article.tabs section
{
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: 1.8em;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   height: 12em;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
   z-index: 0;
}


article.tabs section:first-child
{
   z-index: 1;
}

article.tabs section h2
{
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-weight: normal;
   width:   15%;
   min-height: 1.8em;
   top: -1.8em;
   left: 0px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   color: #999;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 3px ;
   background-color:#0af515;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(2) h2
{
left: 22%;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(3) h2
{
   left: 42.8%;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(4) h2
{
    left: 63.5%;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(5) h2
{
   left: 84.25%;
}


article.tabs section h2 a
{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 1.8em;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: inherit;
   outline: 0 none;
}

article.tabs section:target,
article.tabs section:target h2
{
   color: #333;
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 2;
}

article.tabs section,
article.tabs section h2
{
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
   -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
   -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
   -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
   transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Comment: Good article: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: thanks Kevin! this helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you will be able to do this with css alone, and
[`preventDefault()` probably wont work either](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/e9h9sejm/1/) it looks like the least bad option will be to store the window's scroll position in a variable and "animate" to it...

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/uh98fbde/)**

```
$("a[href^=#]").on("click", function (e) { // when #link is clicked
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // store window scrollTop in var
    $("html, body").animate({ // animate to stored position
        scrollTop: scroll
    });
});
```

Comment: ill accept this as a answer but there are a couple of techniques in the article above that i'm going to try for a css solution. In fairness you rate this solution as the least bad, it works but there is a noticeble scroll to the # and back to the other position. Looks like im using subliminal messaging, but thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done within CSS but a little bit of Javascript will solve it:

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks i might end up using this but i was trying to avoid jQuery where i can.

Comment: This dosen't actually work, the prevent default overrides the entire action.